# Adding items to end of array dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

New to Vuejs, have a question on updating an array.

This is my data (`status_arr`):

```
{
    "Approvals": [
        {
            "name": "Section 1",
            "count": 10692
        }
    ],
    "Declines": [
        {
            "name": "Section 1",
            "count": 1212
        },
        {
            "name": "Section 2",
            "count": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add a `"Pending"` part of the above data dynamically.  I'm not quite understanding the `$set` method on how to accomplish this.  I need to add to the above dataset without effecting the rest of the data in it.

The documentation says to use:

```
this.$set(status_arr, itemIndex, [ { 'name': 'Section 1', 'count': 0 } ]);
```

Not sure how to add the `Pending` part with the data attached and if I'm adding to the array, how does it have an `itemIndex` for me to do so?  Is there a `this.$add` function or something that works like a `pop()`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What should the `status_arr` object look like after adding the *Pending* part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want

```
this.$set(this.status_arr, 'Pending', [{
  name: 'Section 1',
  count: 0
}])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Sean you're welcome. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46416156/283366) for an alternative that is less likely to trigger errors if you try to access `status_arr.Pending` *before* you've populated it

Answer (score 1):

You can change `status_array` to this:

```
{
    "Approvals": [
        {
            "name": "Section 1",
            "count": 10692
        }
    ],
    "Declines": [
        {
            "name": "Section 1",
            "count": 1212
        },
        {
            "name": "Section 2",
            "count": 5
        }
    ],
    "Pending": []
}
```

And when you want to add more item to Pending, you can use:

```
status_array.Pending.push(newEle)
```

Remember, Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also trigger view updates. The wrapped methods are:

- push()
- pop()
- shift()
- unshift()
- splice()
- sort()
- reverse()

Answer (score 0):

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set or this.$set. This is how I achieve it:
A constructor function to return desirable object

```
 addObj(name, count) {
     return {
         name: name,
         count: count
     }
 }
```

Call this function

```
var newObj = new this.addObj('tom', 6);
this.$set(this.status_arr, 'Pending', newObj);
```

And if you want to remove a key val pair:

```
this.$delete(this.status_arr, 'Pending');
```